# How Does Spark Access to data?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I want to use Apache Spark on YARN. So I know that when upload data in HDFS, it partitions that  and distribute across worker nodes. So can somebody explain how does spark access to data ?

Comment: It is quite similar actually. If for example, you read an input file from HDFS, then it will read and partition the file such that it can distribute it to worker nodes. It will do so by serializing the data and sending a given partition to a worker node for processing.

Comment: so a worker node just access to the partition that it received? when i run a query in that node, it just search that partition?

Comment: Yes. Each worker (or more precisely, an Executor) will get a chunk of the data (a partition) and process it.

Comment: You welcome. :)